# Installation Aborted (Psychostats)

Tags: php, windows, installation, xampp

I have tried installing PsychoStats 3.2.8b, but to no avail. The error message is: "Installation Aborted! The installation was halted due to your session either timing out or another installation session was started! You must start over and try again. Be sure not to open a second installation window or it will fail again." I'm trying to install on a fully functional server: Xampp - Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.16.

It appears that the installation script is not setting the cookie required to proceed. The script resides in common.php:

```
<?php
/**
 *  This file is part of PsychoStats.
 *
 *  Written by Jason Morriss
 *  Copyright 2008 Jason Morriss
 *
 *  PsychoStats is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  PsychoStats is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with PsychoStats.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 *  Version: $Id: common.php 565 2008-10-10 12:27:02Z lifo $
 */
if (!defined("PSYCHOSTATS_INSTALL_PAGE")) die("Unauthorized access to " . basename(__FILE__));

define("PS_INSTALL_VERSION", '3.2.8b');

define("PS_ROOTDIR", rtrim(dirname(__DIR__), '/\\'));
define("PS_INSTALLDIR", __DIR__);

// enable some sane error reporting (ignore notice errors) and turn off the magic. 
// we also want to to disable E_STRICT.
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED); 
//set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
/**/
@ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
@ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
/**/

// IIS does not have REQUEST_URI defined (apache specific).
// This URI is handy in certain pages so we create it if needed.
if (empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
}

// read in all of our required libraries for basic functionality!
require_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/includes/functions.php");
require_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/includes/class_DB.php");
require_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/includes/class_PS.php");
require_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/includes/class_CMS.php");
require_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/includes/class_HTTP.php");
require_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/includes/class_session.php");

// try to load the current config
$dbtype = 'mysql';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbport = '';
$dbname = 'psychostats';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbtblprefix = 'ps_';
$site_url = '';
if (file_exists(PS_ROOTDIR . "/config.php") and file_exists(PS_ROOTDIR . "/install/go-dbinit.php")) {
    @include_once(PS_ROOTDIR . "/config.php");
} else {
    echo "You must install game support before you can install PsychoStats, please see INSTALL.md for details.";
    exit;
}

// Initialize our global variables for PsychoStats. 
// Lets be nice to the global Name Space.
$db     = null;
$cms        = null;             // global PsychoCMS object
$php_scnm = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];        // this is used so much we make sure it's global
// Sanitize PHP_SELF and avoid XSS attacks.
// We use the constant in places we know we'll be outputting $PHP_SELF to the user
define("SAFE_PHP_SCNM", htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

// create database handle
$db = PsychoDB::create(array(
    'dbtype' => 'mysql',
    'delaystart' => true,
    'fatal'  => false,
));

// start the PS CMS object
$cms = new PsychoCMS(array(
    'dbhandle'  => &$db,
    'plugin_dir'    => PS_ROOTDIR . '/plugins',
    'site_url'  => $site_url
));

**// this session will not actually store a session in a database or file.
// it's mearly used in the install for cookie support.
$cms->session = new PsychoSession(array(
    'cms'           => $cms,
    'cookiename'        => 'ps_install_sess',
    'cookiesalt'        => '',
    'cookiecompress'    => true,
    'cookieencode'      => true,
    'cookielifeoptions'     => 0,   
    'dbhandle'      => $db,
    'delaystart'        => true,
));**

$cms->init(true); // quick init; no plugins, session or user

$cms->init_theme('default', array( 
    'theme_default' => 'default',
    'theme_opt' => 'install_theme',
    'in_db'     => false,
    'force_theme'   => true,
    'fetch_compile' => false,
    'compile_id'    => 'install',
    'compile_dir'   => null,
    'js_compress'   => false,
    'css_compress'  => false,
    'template_dir'  => __DIR__ . '/themes',
    'theme_url' => null,
));
$cms->theme->load_styles();
$cms->theme->assign(array(
    'SELF'          => SAFE_PHP_SCNM,
    'install_version'   => PS_INSTALL_VERSION
));

// ----------------------------------
function init_session_opts($delete = false) {
    global $cms;
    $opts = $cms->session->load_session_options();
    if ($delete || !$opts || !$opts['install']) {
        $cms->session->set_opts(array('install' => uniqid(rand(),true)), true);
        $cms->session->save_session_options();
        $opts = $cms->session->load_session_options();
    }
    return $opts;
}

// load DB conf from POST'ed form, or session variables if no form variable was found
function load_db_opts($conf = null) {
    global $cms;
    $list = array('dbhost','dbport','dbname','dbuser','dbpass','dbtblprefix');
    $opts = $cms->session->load_session_options();
    foreach ($list as $var) {
        if ($conf and is_array($conf) and array_key_exists($var, $conf)) {
            $GLOBALS[$var] = $conf[$var];
#           print "CONF: $var == '$conf[$var]'<br>";
        } else if (array_key_exists($var, $opts)) {
            $GLOBALS[$var] = $opts[$var];
#           print "OPTS: $var == '$opts[$var]'<br>";
        }
    }
}

function save_db_opts() {
    global $cms, $dbhost, $dbport, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbtblprefix;
    $opts = $cms->session->load_session_options();
    $opts['dbhost'] = $dbhost;
    $opts['dbport'] = $dbport;
    $opts['dbname'] = $dbname;
    $opts['dbuser'] = $dbuser;`your text`
    $opts['dbpass'] = $dbpass;
    $opts['dbtblprefix'] = $dbtblprefix;
    $cms->session->save_session_options($opts);
}

?>
```

I'm not a coder, so I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers? We can't really help you debug third party software/code not behaving as expected. I also don't seem to be able to find where you got this from. All repos I've found don't have the same version as you say you're using.

Comment: The developer hasn't updated it in ages. Drek282 has been involved in trying to update it to work with PHP 7 and possibly PHP 8. https://github.com/Drek282/PsychoStats. I've posted an issue there, but we've been unable to solve it.

Comment: _"trying to update it to work with PHP 7 and possibly PHP 8."_ - Are you sure they succeeded to make it compatible with PHP 7.4 then? We would need to look through the codebase to even begin to try and understand where it does what and how, which isn't something we will do here. You need to do some debugging to narrow the issue down and then post all relevant code.

Comment: Figured out what it was. The script was trying to set secure cookie. My site is not set up for SSL. I changed 'cookiesecure' => 1 , to 'cookiesecure' => 0, in class_session.php and was able to complete the install.